# Find Product with SKU number and ADD or SUBTRACT from Inventory Stock

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sum, product, addition

I hope somebody here can help. We've been trying to create a dynamic inventory list with all the products, each given an SKU and unit size. Most buttons are now working, but we are still missing the script for the UPDATE buttons in the INStock and OUTStock sheets.

[An example of a clear OUTStock sheet, how it should look after clicking update and having all the products sent/added to inventory list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T8kF.png)

[Example of products put into INStock sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTftv.png)

[Inventory sheet, where products are to be added/subtracted from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE4W5.png)

Essentially, once clicking UPDATE in INStock, all the items listed would be found via their respective SKU code in the Inventory sheet and added to the current stock. The boxes on column E of INStock would be added to their respective products in column C in the inventory sheet, and the individual bottles would be transferred from column F of the INStock sheet to their respective products on column D in the inventory sheet.

OUTStock on the other hand would be any stock taken out from the cellar, so the same concept but instead of adding to previously said columns it would subtract from.

After this process columns B2:B30 and E2:F30 from INStock/OUTStock need to have their content cleared.
I've come across many questions where people had a similar concept for a button but none looking up a specific product to add the quantity to. It would be amazing if somebody could help with the right functions.

Many thanks for your time!

UPDATE:
Thanks @Irvin for the help. I've added the script and modified the outStock function as I understood, however I'm having some issues regarding the subtraction. Please see attached photos for more info. I've also included the log execution for that function:

[Initial Stock count of Las Rocas (14 bottles)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPUUS.png)

[outStock update removing 2 bottles from inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi14y.png)

[Too many bottles removed and put into negative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsCQb.png)

```
function outStock(outstock, inventory){ //Function for OUTStock sheet data
  var skus = [];
  var boxes = [];
  var bottles = [];

  for(var x = 2; x <= outstock.getDataRange().getLastRow();x++){ //Get all SKUs,Boxes and Bottles from OUTStock sheet
    skus.push(outstock.getRange(x,1).getValue());
    boxes.push(outstock.getRange(x,5).getValue());
    bottles.push(outstock.getRange(x,6).getValue());
  }

  for (var y = 3; y <= inventory.getDataRange().getLastRow(); y++){ //Check Inventory sheet by SKU code from OUTStock
      skus.forEach(res => {
        if(res == inventory.getRange(y,1).getValue()){
          var boxUpdate = boxes[skus.indexOf(res)] - inventory.getRange(y,3).getValue(); //ADD the sum of the box value from OUTStock and BOX cell value on Inventory to array boxUpdate
          var bottleUpdate = bottles[skus.indexOf(res)] - inventory.getRange(y,4).getValue(); //ADD the sum of the bottle value from OUTStock and INDIVIDUAL cell value on Inventory to array bottleUpdate
          inventory.getRange(y,3).setValue(boxUpdate); //Update BOX column cell value on Inventory sheet 
          inventory.getRange(y,4).setValue(bottleUpdate); //Update INDIVIDUAL column cell value on Inventory sheet
          outstock.getRange("B2:B"+outstock.getDataRange().getLastRow()).clearContent(); //Clears all contents on B2:B(the last row your sheet has)
          outstock.getRange("E2:F"+outstock.getDataRange().getLastRow()).clearContent(); //Clears all contents on E2:F(the last row your sheet has)
          Logger.log("Found Match for OUTStock SKU code "+res+" on Inventory sheet at row #" + y+"\n==OUTSTOCK DATA==\nSKU: "+res+"\nBox: "+boxes[skus.indexOf(res)]+"\nBottle: "+bottles[skus.indexOf(res)]+"\n==UPDATED INVENTORY==\nCell C"+y+" was updated to "+boxUpdate+"\nCell D"+y+" was updated to "+bottleUpdate);
        }
      });
  }
  Logger.log(" Done Updating SKU codes: " + skus + " on Inventory sheet");
}
```

Other than that it seems to work perfectly. Please see below the execution log of the photo example given:

[As can be seen, update to -12 instead of 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1U7P.png)

I hope I'm clear on what the issue is. Many thanks again!

UPDATE 2:
As for the Script, I've placed it all under one file with the same main function left unchanged (update) and assigned the same update function to both instock and outstock buttons (see picture) Here is the full script:

[Example of function assigned to OUTStock Update button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6mRp.png)

```
function update() { //Main function
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var instock = sheet.getSheetByName('INStock');
  var outstock = sheet.getSheetByName('OUTStock');
  var inventory = sheet.getSheetByName('Inventory');

  if(sheet.getSheetName() == "INStock"){ 
    Logger.log("Run update for INStock sheet"); //Logs the result for review
    inStock(instock, inventory); //Runs the function for INStock
  }else if(sheet.getSheetName() == "OUTStock"){
    Logger.log("Run update for OUTStock sheet"); //Logs the result for review
    outStock(outstock, inventory); //Runs the function for OUTStock
  }else{ //IF statement if you run test your code from the script editor
    Logger.log("Please select either INStock or OUTStock sheet on your spreadsheet"); //Logs the result for review
  }
}

function inStock(instock, inventory){ //Function for INStock sheet data
  var skus = [];
  var boxes = [];
  var bottles = [];

  for(var x = 2; x <= instock.getDataRange().getLastRow();x++){ //Get all SKUs,Boxes and Bottles from INStock sheet
    skus.push(instock.getRange(x,1).getValue());
    boxes.push(instock.getRange(x,5).getValue());
    bottles.push(instock.getRange(x,6).getValue());
  }

  for (var y = 3; y <= inventory.getDataRange().getLastRow(); y++){ //Check Inventory sheet by SKU code from INStock
      skus.forEach(res => {
        if(res == inventory.getRange(y,1).getValue()){
          var boxUpdate = boxes[skus.indexOf(res)] + inventory.getRange(y,3).getValue(); //ADD the sum of the box value from INStock and BOX cell value on Inventory to array boxUpdate
          var bottleUpdate = bottles[skus.indexOf(res)] + inventory.getRange(y,4).getValue(); //ADD the sum of the bottle value from INStock and INDIVIDUAL cell value on Inventory to array bottleUpdate
          inventory.getRange(y,3).setValue(boxUpdate); //Update BOX column cell value on Inventory sheet 
          inventory.getRange(y,4).setValue(bottleUpdate); //Update INDIVIDUAL column cell value on Inventory sheet
          instock.getRange("B2:B"+instock.getDataRange().getLastRow()).clearContent(); //Clears all contents on B2:B(the last row your sheet has)
          instock.getRange("E2:F"+instock.getDataRange().getLastRow()).clearContent(); //Clears all contents on E2:F(the last row your sheet has)
          Logger.log("Found Match for INStock SKU code "+res+" on Inventory sheet at row #" + y+"\n==INSTOCK DATA==\nSKU: "+res+"\nBox: "+boxes[skus.indexOf(res)]+"\nBottle: "+bottles[skus.indexOf(res)]+"\n==UPDATED INVENTORY==\nCell C"+y+" was updated to "+boxUpdate+"\nCell D"+y+" was updated to "+bottleUpdate);
        }
      });
  }
  Logger.log(" Done Updating SKU codes: " + skus + " on Inventory sheet");
}

function outStock(outstock, inventory){ //Function for OUTStock sheet data
  var skus = [];
  var boxes = [];
  var bottles = [];

  for(var x = 2; x <= outstock.getDataRange().getLastRow();x++){ //Get all SKUs,Boxes and Bottles from OUTStock sheet
    skus.push(outstock.getRange(x,1).getValue());
    boxes.push(outstock.getRange(x,5).getValue());
    bottles.push(outstock.getRange(x,6).getValue());
  }

  for (var y = 3; y <= inventory.getDataRange().getLastRow(); y++){ //Check Inventory sheet by SKU code from OUTStock
      skus.forEach(res => {
        if(res == inventory.getRange(y,1).getValue()){
          var boxUpdate = boxes[skus.indexOf(res)] - inventory.getRange(y,3).getValue(); //ADD the sum of the box value from OUTStock and BOX cell value on Inventory to array boxUpdate
          var bottleUpdate = bottles[skus.indexOf(res)] - inventory.getRange(y,4).getValue(); //ADD the sum of the bottle value from OUTStock and INDIVIDUAL cell value on Inventory to array bottleUpdate
          inventory.getRange(y,3).setValue(boxUpdate); //Update BOX column cell value on Inventory sheet 
          inventory.getRange(y,4).setValue(bottleUpdate); //Update INDIVIDUAL column cell value on Inventory sheet
          outstock.getRange("B2:B"+outstock.getDataRange().getLastRow()).clearContent(); //Clears all contents on B2:B(the last row your sheet has)
          outstock.getRange("E2:F"+outstock.getDataRange().getLastRow()).clearContent(); //Clears all contents on E2:F(the last row your sheet has)
          Logger.log("Found Match for OUTStock SKU code "+res+" on Inventory sheet at row #" + y+"\n==OUTSTOCK DATA==\nSKU: "+res+"\nBox: "+boxes[skus.indexOf(res)]+"\nBottle: "+bottles[skus.indexOf(res)]+"\n==UPDATED INVENTORY==\nCell C"+y+" was updated to "+boxUpdate+"\nCell D"+y+" was updated to "+bottleUpdate);
        }
      });
  }
  Logger.log(" Done Updating SKU codes: " + skus + " on Inventory sheet");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**RECOMMENDED SOLUTION:**

Based on your statement, you want your update process to be like this:

1. Get all SKU codes from INStock/OUTstock sheet
2. Update the **Inventory** sheet's **BOX** column with:

   **INStock Box** value +/- **Inventory Box** current value on rows with matched SKU code from **INStock/OUTstock**
3. Update the **Inventory** sheet's **INDIVIDUAL** column with:

   **INStock Bottle** value +/- **Inventory INDIVIDUAL** current value on rows with matched SKU code from **INStock/OUTstock**
4. Clear contents on columns B:B & F:E on INStock/OUTstock

With that, I have created sample sheets based on your attached examples (tested INStock sheet) and created a script below:

**INStock** sheet:

[image]

**Inventory** sheet:

[image]

***Script*** that you can use as a reference:

```
/**
 * Custom Update funtion for INStock and OUTStock sheets
 */

function update() { //Main function
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var instock = sheet.getSheetByName('INStock');
  var outstock = sheet.getSheetByName('OUTStock');
  var inventory = sheet.getSheetByName('Inventory');

  if(sheet.getSheetName() == "INStock"){ 
    Logger.log("Run update for INStock sheet"); //Logs the result for review
    inStock(instock, inventory); //Runs the function for INStock
  }else if(sheet.getSheetName() == "OUTStock"){
    Logger.log("Run update for OUTStock sheet"); //Logs the result for review
    outStock(outstock, inventory); //Runs the function for OUTStock
  }else{ //IF statement if you run test your code from the script editor
    Logger.log("Please select either INStock or OUTStock sheet on your spreadsheet"); //Logs the result for review
  }
}

function inStock(instock, inventory){ //Function for INStock sheet data
  var skus = [];
  var boxes = [];
  var bottles = [];

  for(var x = 2; x <= instock.getDataRange().getLastRow();x++){ //Get all SKUs,Boxes and Bottles from INStock sheet
    skus.push(instock.getRange(x,1).getValue());
    boxes.push(instock.getRange(x,5).getValue());
    bottles.push(instock.getRange(x,6).getValue());
  }

  for (var y = 3; y <= inventory.getDataRange().getLastRow(); y++){ //Check Inventory sheet by SKU code from INStock
      skus.forEach(res => {
        if(res == inventory.getRange(y,1).getValue()){
          var boxUpdate = boxes[skus.indexOf(res)] + inventory.getRange(y,3).getValue(); //ADD the sum of the box value from INStock and BOX cell value on Inventory to array boxUpdate
          var bottleUpdate = bottles[skus.indexOf(res)] + inventory.getRange(y,4).getValue(); //ADD the sum of the bottle value from INStock and INDIVIDUAL cell value on Inventory to array bottleUpdate
          inventory.getRange(y,3).setValue(boxUpdate); //Update BOX column cell value on Inventory sheet 
          inventory.getRange(y,4).setValue(bottleUpdate); //Update INDIVIDUAL column cell value on Inventory sheet
          instock.getRange("B2:B"+instock.getDataRange().getLastRow()).clearContent(); //Clears all contents on B2:B(the last row your sheet has)
          instock.getRange("E2:F"+instock.getDataRange().getLastRow()).clearContent(); //Clears all contents on E2:F(the last row your sheet has)
          Logger.log("Found Match for INStock SKU code "+res+" on Inventory sheet at row #" + y+"\n==INSTOCK DATA==\nSKU: "+res+"\nBox: "+boxes[skus.indexOf(res)]+"\nBottle: "+bottles[skus.indexOf(res)]+"\n==UPDATED INVENTORY==\nCell C"+y+" was updated to "+boxUpdate+"\nCell D"+y+" was updated to "+bottleUpdate);
        }
      });
  }
  Logger.log(" Done Updating SKU codes: " + skus + " on Inventory sheet");
}

function outStock(outstock, inventory){ //Function for OUTStock sheet data
var skus = [];
var boxes = [];
var bottles = [];

for(var x = 2; x <= outstock.getDataRange().getLastRow();x++){ //Get all SKUs,Boxes and Bottles from OUTStock sheet
  skus.push(outstock.getRange(x,1).getValue());
  boxes.push(outstock.getRange(x,5).getValue());
  bottles.push(outstock.getRange(x,6).getValue());
}

for (var y = 3; y <= inventory.getDataRange().getLastRow(); y++){ //Check Inventory sheet by SKU code from OUTStock
    skus.forEach(res => {
      if(res == inventory.getRange(y,1).getValue()){
        var boxUpdate =  inventory.getRange(y,3).getValue() - boxes[skus.indexOf(res)]; //ADD the sum of the box value from OUTStock and BOX cell value on Inventory to array boxUpdate
        var bottleUpdate = inventory.getRange(y,4).getValue() - bottles[skus.indexOf(res)]; //ADD the sum of the bottle value from OUTStock and INDIVIDUAL cell value on Inventory to array bottleUpdate
        inventory.getRange(y,3).setValue(boxUpdate); //Update BOX column cell value on Inventory sheet 
        inventory.getRange(y,4).setValue(bottleUpdate); //Update INDIVIDUAL column cell value on Inventory sheet
        outstock.getRange("B2:B"+outstock.getDataRange().getLastRow()).clearContent(); //Clears all contents on B2:B(the last row your sheet has)
        outstock.getRange("E2:F"+outstock.getDataRange().getLastRow()).clearContent(); //Clears all contents on E2:F(the last row your sheet has)
        Logger.log("Found Match for OUTStock SKU code "+res+" on Inventory sheet at row #" + y+"\n==OUTSTOCK DATA==\nSKU: "+res+"\nBox: "+boxes[skus.indexOf(res)]+"\nBottle: "+bottles[skus.indexOf(res)]+"\n==UPDATED INVENTORY==\nCell C"+y+" was updated to "+boxUpdate+"\nCell D"+y+" was updated to "+bottleUpdate);
      }
    });
}
Logger.log(" Done Updating SKU codes: " + skus + " on Inventory sheet");
}
```

**RESULT:**

After putting the `update` custom function on the UPDATE button on **INStock** sheet to run the script, here's the result:

[image]

Result on **Inventory** sheet:

[image]

**Log Execution result**, where you can review what happened on the script:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Irvin, please see the update for the only error I've encountered. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Amazing @Irvin Jay G., the modified script works perfectly! Sorry for my mistakes, new to the whole Google Script scene. Many thanks again!

Comment: @Patxi Fernandez Coster, you're welcome. The reason why you've got -12 as a result was because the box (2) was subtracted to the INDIVIDUAL cell data (14) on Inventory sheet (2-14 = -12). I have updated my OUTStock function on my answer, specifically on the var boxUpdate & var bottleUpdate, where the inventory INDIVIDUAL data is subtracted to the Box data from OUTStock.